# Merging dataframes that have different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = data.frame(Bird_ID = c(1:6), Sex = c("Male","Female","Male","Male","Male","UNK"), Age.years =c("2","4","8","2","12","1"))

df2 = data.frame(Bird_ID = c(7), Sex = c("Female"), date.fledged= c("19/10/2021"))

df1
# Bird_ID Sex Age.years
# 1 Male 2
# 2 Female 4
# 3 Male 8
# 4 Male 2
# 5 Male 12
# 6 UNK 1
       
df2
# Bird_ID Sex Date.fledged
# 7 Female 19/10/2021
```

- My first dataframe (`df1`) is my database where I have all my birds records with useful informations
- My second dataframe (`df2`) is the "updater". I want to merge these informations to the main database (`df1`) and the output would be like this:

```r
dfmerged = data.frame(Bird_ID = c(1:7), Sex = c("Male","Female","Male","Male","Male","UNK","Female"), Age.years =c("2","4","8","2","12","1",NA))`

dfmerged
# Bird_ID Sex Age.years
# 1 Male 2
# 2 Female 4
# 3 Male 8
# 4 Male 2
# 5 Male 12
# 6 UNK 1
# 7 Female NA
```

How can I update the bird database `df1` using information from `df2`and keeping only (and all) columns that are in the main database `df1`? For example here `dfmerged` keeps only the columns from `df1`,drops the "Date.fledged" column from `df2` and bird 7 has NA as "Age.years" because data is missing (and that is the wanted output).

Comment: Does "update" mean adding new data or does it include updating existing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  bind_rows(df2) %>% 
  select(names(df1))
```

This returns

```r
  Bird_ID    Sex Age.years
1       1   Male         2
2       2 Female         4
3       3   Male         8
4       4   Male         2
5       5   Male        12
6       6    UNK         1
7       7 Female      <NA>
```

Comment: thks. that does the job

Answer (score 1):

You may do a full join.

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c('Bird_ID', 'Sex'), all = TRUE)[-4]

#  Bird_ID    Sex Age.years
#1       1   Male         2
#2       2 Female         4
#3       3   Male         8
#4       4   Male         2
#5       5   Male        12
#6       6    UNK         1
#7       7 Female      <NA>
```

In `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(df1, df2, by = c('Bird_ID', 'Sex')) %>%
  select(-date.fledged)
```